# How to work with a reference to a JS object inside WASM, which is compiled from C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, clang, llvm, webassembly

I'm trying to develop a C++ library that will work with HTML elements. So, I need classes that will store references to `Element`, which I will get through `document.getElementById("id")`. Since I can't work with the DOM directly from WASM, I need to get a reference from the imported JS function somehow in C++ when I call that function. But I don't quite understand what it's supposed to look like.

In the documentation I found a class called `WebAssembly.Table`. As far as I understand, in this table I can just store references that I can access from WASM. But I don't really understand how to access this table from C++. I haven't yet compiled C++ into WASM, but for now I'm just learning how I can do it. As far as I understand, I can do this with Clang by setting the target platform as WASM.

So, are there any special types in Clang for transferring references from JS? Builtin functions to access `WebAssembly.Table`?

The **pseudocode** of what I mean:

```cpp
Ref DOMGetElementById();
void DOMChangeText(Ref element);

class CMyElement
{
private:
    Ref Element;

public:
    CMyElement() :
        Element{ DOMGetElementById() } { }

    void ChangeText()
    {
        DOMChangeText(Element);
    }
};

int main()
{
    CMyElement myElement;

    myElement.ChangeText();

    return 0;
}
```

```js
const wasmImports =
{
    env:
    {
        DOMGetElementById: () =>
        {
            return document.getElementById("myElement");
        },

        DOMChangeText: (element) =>
        {
            element.textContent = "Hello world."
        }
    }
};

const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmCode);
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, wasmImports);

console.log(wasmInstance.exports.main());
```

I understand that the code above most likely cannot be implemented due to the fact that GC has to count references.

Okay, apparently this is why we have to use a class called `WebAssembly.Table`. But I can't figure out what I should call in C++ to get a value from this table and pass it to the called function.

I imagine that Clang should provide me with some functions or special types that I should use for such a task. But I could not find it.

So I need an explanation of how I can implement my idea.

Comment: Reference counted objects in C++:`std::shared_ptr`.